# Xslt Saxon processor - All files in a directory

Tags: java, xml, batch-file, xslt, saxon

I have this batch file running which processes an xml file in the /input directory.

```
java  -jar c:/SaxonHE9-6-0-6J/saxon9he.jar -s:D:/hdbook-Convertor/input/  -xsl:C:\Automation\hdbook-convertor.xml  -o:D:\hdbook-Convertor\output -xmlversion:1.0
```

I want to be able to process the sub directories and the files in them, the structure being [image]

and then moving all the processed files to the output folder. I cant see how to make `-s:D:/hdbook-Convertor/input/` loop through all the sub directories?

Comment: What is Saxon supposed to do with the various `pdf` files anyway?

Comment: nothing, its just taking the xml and using a style sheet to reformat it

Answer (score 1):

Try using the collection() function within the transformation itself:

```
<xsl:template name="main">
  <xsl:for-each select="collection('file:///D:/hdbook-Convertor/input/?recurse=yes;select=*.xml')">
    <xsl:result-document href="output/{tokenize(document-uri(.), '/')[last()]">
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:result-document>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Hi Michael, Im using a style sheet like this

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="/">
   <export>
    <order>
     <header>
      <xsl:for-each select="export/order/header">
       <id><xsl:value-of select="id"/></id>
       <datecreated><xsl:value-of select="datecreated"/></datecreated>`

how would i specify the source in your example?

Comment: Just add the supplied template rule with name="main", and then invoke the stylesheet with -it:main if running from the command line, omitting the -s (source) option.

Comment: is there an issue with the path to the input directory?`C:\Automation>java  -jar c:/SaxonHE9-6-0-6J/saxon9he.jar -it:main  -xsl:C:\Autom
ation\hdbook-convertor.xml -o:D:\hdbook-Convertor\output -xmlversion:1.0
Output is a directory, but input is not`

Comment: Specify a file as the output, not a directory. It's used for any output outside the scope of xsl:result-document, and relative URIs in xsl:result-document are relative to this location.

Comment: thats moved me on to another error "The requested initial main template dose not exist" im a little lost now. i have added your supplied code to the top and bottom of the style sheet is that correct?

Comment: Assuming the message is actually "The requested initial template main does not exist" (and not what you wrote), then it is saying the stylesheet doesn't contain a template with the attribute name="main".

Comment: Ive corrected that error, and now this one "SXXP0003: Error reported by XML parser: The prefix "xsl" for element "xsl:template" is not bound." - Thank you for your help on this its greatly appreciated

Comment: That's an absolutely standard and basic error message meaning that you've failed to declare the "xsl" namespace prefix in your stylesheet. But please: don't ask supplementary questions in comments. It's a new question, so if you really need to ask it then it should be a new question, not a comment on the answer to a previous question. (Having said that, the question would almost certainly be downvoted because the most basic reading or research will tell you what's wrong.)

Answer (score 0):

Try this (untested)

```
for /f "delims=" %%f in ('dir /b /s /ad D:\hdbook-Convertor\input') do echo java -jar c:/SaxonHE9-6-0-6J/saxon9he.jar -s:"%%~dpf" -xsl:C:\Automation\hdbook-convertor.xml -o:D:\hdbook-Convertor\output -xmlversion:1.0
```

If the commands look right and work well (try a couple of them manually), remove "echo" for actual bulk execution.

Comment: thanks parag, that kind of work, the script looked into each directory but saxon didn't perform the xlst conversion. See the command line output below

Comment: C:\Automation>for /F "delims=" %f in ('dir /b /s /ad D:\hdbook-Convertor\input')
 do java -jar c:/SaxonHE9-6-0-6J/saxon9he.jar -s:"%~dpf" -xsl:C:\Automation\hdbook-convertor.xml  -o:D:\hdbook-Convertor\output -xmlversion:1.0

C:\Automation>java -jar c:/SaxonHE9-6-0-6J/saxon9he.jar -s:"D:\hdbook-Convertor\
input\" -xsl:C:\Automation\hdbook-convertor.xml  -o:D:\hdbook-Convertor\output -
xmlversion:1.0
No stylesheet file name
Saxon-HE 9.6.0.6J from Saxonica
Usage: see http://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation/using-xsl/commandline.html

Comment: Format: net.sf.saxon.Transform options params
Options available: -? -a -catalog -config -cr -dtd -expand -explain -ext -im -in
it -it -l -m -now -o -opt -or -outval -p -quit -r -repeat -s -sa -strip -t -T -t
hreads -TJ -TP -traceout -tree -u -val -versionmsg -warnings -x -xi -xmlversion
-xsd -xsdversion -xsiloc -xsl -xsltversion -y
Use -XYZ:? for details of option XYZ

Comment: Params:
  param=value           Set stylesheet string parameter
  +param=filename       Set stylesheet document parameter
  ?param=expression     Set stylesheet parameter using XPath
  !param=value          Set serialization parameter

Comment: Umm, I don't see why it would fail. Maybe you should add "echo" after "do" to see if the command is right. Try running some echoed commands manually and tweak appropriately. See the updated answer for echo.

Comment: Each single conversion launches a new JVM so converting a bigger number of files will take ages.